# A positive word for "intolerance towards intolerant people"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any positive word that means "Intolerance towards intolerant people"?

If I need just one word to describe in a positive way the majority of people in a country who have now become intolerant towards sexist people or racist people what word can be used to describe such a situation, a situation where tolerance for sexist or racist people has decreased?

Comment: Otherwise known as the paradox of tolerance... are you looking for something in general, or to be used as a sort of comeback?

Comment: The term is, of course, *politically correct*.

Comment: ... no intolerance permitted here...

Comment: @sumelic: In a positive way.

Comment: If the people of interest are putting efforts and creating awareness among the society all over the country, I would call them 'revolutionaries'. These people are trying to break out of the victim mentality and seeking freedom.

Comment: I think [***rectitude***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rectitude) has quite a lot going for it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking that you wanted to imply negative connotations, I had suggested ***self-righteous***, but if you want to imply positive connotations, perhaps you can use ***[righteous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/righteous)***

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out that the original poster wants a word with positive connotations, so I edited the question to make it clear. Sorry to make an edit like this after you've already posted an answer to the previous version of the question. In the future, I would advise waiting to post until it's clearer what kind of answer the questioner wants.

Comment: @sumelic Don't worry, you did the right think, it was my mistake. I have edited the answer to reflect the change in connotation without taking Julia's answer

Comment: I think OP was looking for a synonym of "social justice warrior" that is not pejorative.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a term that is specific against intolerance, but the people of the country may be:

> **Principled**: acting in accordance with morality and showing recognition
>   of right and wrong.
>
> **Scrupulous**: very concerned to avoid doing wrong.
>
> **Punctilious**: showing great attention to correct behaviour.

or as a whole have:

> **Probity**: the quality of having strong moral principles; honesty and
>   decency.

Answer (score 2):

How about [indignation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indignation) (and indignant)?

**indignation**: strong displeasure at something considered unjust, offensive, insulting, or base; righteous anger.

**indignant**: angered at something unjust or wrong.

*More and more people have become indignant about racism*

Answer (score 1):

> **Righteous anger** is typically a reactive emotion of anger over perceived mistreatment, insult, or malice. It is akin to what is called the sense of injustice. In some Christian doctrines, righteous anger is considered the only form of anger which is not sinful, e.g., when Jesus drove the money lenders out of the temple (Gospel of Matthew 21). -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Righteous_indignation)